# Is there any way to extract child models from 3d model binary file with python

Tags: python, model, blender, 3d-model

I have the models of an old game that are serialised in to binary files.Game serialised bunch of SO1 files from the source code into single binary file to make a complete model with child models(like collision mesh for physics and debris mesh for when for example the model destroyed or something). And then we have script to import these binaries into blender.

But the problem is that script only read the basic mesh of these serialised binaries.It does not extract other mesh like debris.So what I want to do is to write a script to extract all the meshes from the serialised models and import into Blender. Is there any way to extract the child models from the model like different meshes or stuff. Is there any resources that you can share or any tip that might help.

[Here is the sample of the serialised model](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cL1UE1GuhtzfXt74UZOr09bykSK60jBL)

Any kind of resources or tip would be really help.
Thanks

**Update**
There are two kind of models files i have one from source code and are read able and the code looks like this.

```
Object : hybrid howitzer middle
Matrix : 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 
0.000000, 1.000000, 0.651333, -0.272336, 148.104279
Verts (28)
{
  32.776379, -4.732749, 20.940834
  32.776371, 13.366718, 20.940834
 -32.248661, -4.732746, 20.940876
 -32.248661, 13.366739, 20.940876
 36.352749, 22.416452, 5.266243
-35.825039, 22.416466, 5.266243
-35.825047, -13.782484, 5.266245
-32.248669, 13.366730, -10.408346
-32.248669, -4.732749, -10.408345
36.352749, -13.782476, 5.266245
32.776371, 13.366718, -10.408346
32.776371, -4.732749, -10.408345
-12.917832, -31.803804, -21.983011
-12.917823, 9.673828, -21.983013
0.099994, -57.036156, 19.674057
0.099991, -13.068811, 19.674057
13.117827, 9.673826, -21.983017
13.117826, -31.803808, -21.983015
-21.661488, -9.395690, -24.962152
-39.987076, -41.058319, -13.630542
-21.661488, -9.395624, -2.298935
-21.661503, -85.191681, -24.962152
-21.661503, -85.191628, -2.298935
21.661484, -9.395710, -24.962194
39.987076, -41.058342, -13.630584
21.661484, -9.395645, -2.298975
21.661510, -85.191711, -24.962194
21.661510, -85.191643, -2.298975
```

}

and the other one is serialised files there extension are ".bin_n" and are not readable.

Comment: Do you know how the file format looks internally? Does it e.g. list number of nodes, then (x,y,z) that often, then some separator? Or does it tell you at which byte number the models start?

Comment: Ok so the binary file can't be readable but the file form game source code are readable it's look like this the x,y,z  `Object : hybrid howitzer middle
Matrix : 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.651333, -0.272336, 148.104279
Verts (28)
{
 32.776379, -4.732749, 20.940834
 32.776371, 13.366718, 20.940834
}` i'll update the question with the code.

Comment: Do you know the format of the serialized files? Did you search for the extension? Open them with a hex editor, maybe there is a header that will give you a hint.

Comment: The format of serialised file is .bin_n which i couldn't find. I think I need to open the ascii format file which are from game source code with hex editor. but then again these files are in ascii format I need to serialised them into bin_n which i don't know how to do .I only have script to import bin_n file into blender

Comment: Did you look at the script? Does it mention the format?

Comment: It starts with this... fileName = "smallbox.bin_n" #Change this to whatever model you want to extract. and it's just pick the file like that and start reading the strings and numbers and meshes etc. I'm guessing the script using struct.unpack() method to unpack with string format or something!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207587/discussion-between-joe-and-osaf).